# Python parsing and iterating through json data

Tags: python, json, api

```
#current forecast
current_api = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='
current_url_zip = current_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'Zip': zip})
#current_url_key = 

json_data = requests.get(future_url_key).json()

#print (json_data)
future_temp_day_0 = json_data['list'][0]['main']['temp'] #current day
future_temp_day_1 = json_data['list'][1]['main']['temp'] #tomorrow
future_description_day_0 = json_data['list'][0]['weather']['description'] #current description
future_description_day_1 = json_data['list'][1]['weather']['description'] #current description
#Kelvin to F conversion
fTemp_0 = int((future_temp_day_0 - 273.15) * (9/5) + (32))
fTemp_1 = int((future_temp_day_1 - 273.15) * (9/5) + (32))
```

So I am using the openweathermap api. I want to be able to pull the current day [temperature][weather description] and tomorrows [temperature][weather description]. The problem is when I try to reference the [weather description] it pulls it from `json_data['list'][3]` and not `json_data['list'][1]`. It iterates to the next spot even though I am referencing the `[1]` item.

```
{  
   "cod":"200",
   "message":0.0122,
   "cnt":40,
   "list":[  
      {  
         "dt":1519074000,
         "main":{  
            "temp":283.99,
            "temp_min":281.801,
            "temp_max":283.99,
            "pressure":989.94,
            "sea_level":1029.29,
            "grnd_level":989.94,
            "humidity":52,
            "temp_kf":2.19
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":801,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"few clouds",
               "icon":"02d"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":20
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":3.36,
            "deg":325.001
         },
         "rain":{
         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"d"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2018-02-19 21:00:00"
      },
      {  
         "dt":1519084800,
         "main":{  
            "temp":282.64,
            "temp_min":281.177,
            "temp_max":282.64,
            "pressure":990.6,
            "sea_level":1029.94,
            "grnd_level":990.6,
            "humidity":47,
            "temp_kf":1.46
         },
         "weather":[  
            {  
               "id":802,
               "main":"Clouds",
               "description":"scattered clouds",
               "icon":"03n"
            }
         ],
         "clouds":{  
            "all":36
         },
         "wind":{  
            "speed":3.17,
            "deg":319.502
         },
         "rain":{
         },
         "sys":{  
            "pod":"n"
         },
         "dt_txt":"2018-02-20 00:00:00"
      }
```

Comment: Edit the question to include a sample of the json return data.

Comment: @JohnGordon updated

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you're accessing the weather description.  Include that code please.

Comment: @JohnGordon updated

Comment: Your code doesn't match your json structure.  Are you sure you gave us what you are _actually running_?  `json_data['list'][0]['weather']['description']` should throw an exception - `json_data['list'][0]['weather']` is a _list_.  It has to be indexed _numerically_, not by a string key.

Answer (score 0):

The `weather` key contains a list of dicts, so you should use `[0]` if you want the description of the first entry of the list:

```
future_description_day_0 = json_data['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
future_description_day_1 = json_data['list'][1]['weather'][0]['description']
```

Comment: I believe I tried that, if I did printed the ID of the dictionary it would print the next dictionary in the list. I can update tomorrow with more information when I get into the office. Sorry, I don't have the full file on hand at the moment.